# Constant BCCode 109 BSOD, WinDbg Analysis Inconclusive

Tags: windows-7, bsod, minidumps, windbg

The last install I did was BlueStacks and the random BSODs rolled in. It's always BCCode 109 and says ntoskrnl.sys is the cause. I used WinDbg to analyze the minidump. Can someone help analyze these results?

Here are the initial results:

> Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
>
> BugCheck 109, {a3a039d8a712d637, b3b7465ef9911381, fffff880009be640, 3}
>
> Probably caused by : Unknown_Image ( ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE )
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

When I ran the !analyze -v I got the following output:

```
CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION (109)
This bugcheck is generated when the kernel detects that critical kernel code or
data have been corrupted. There are generally three causes for a corruption:
1) A driver has inadvertently or deliberately modified critical kernel code
 or data. See http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/64bitPatching.mspx
2) A developer attempted to set a normal kernel breakpoint using a kernel
 debugger that was not attached when the system was booted. Normal breakpoints,
 "bp", can only be set if the debugger is attached at boot time. Hardware
 breakpoints, "ba", can be set at any time.
3) A hardware corruption occurred, e.g. failing RAM holding kernel code or data.
Arguments:
Arg1: a3a039d8a712d637, Reserved
Arg2: b3b7465ef9911381, Reserved
Arg3: fffff880009be640, Failure type dependent information
Arg4: 0000000000000003, Type of corrupted region, can be
    0 : A generic data region
    1 : Modification of a function or .pdata
    2 : A processor IDT
    3 : A processor GDT
    4 : Type 1 process list corruption
    5 : Type 2 process list corruption
    6 : Debug routine modification
    7 : Critical MSR modification

Debugging Details:
------------------


>CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x109

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0>

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK

Followup: MachineOwner
```

So far after some research, I'm assuming it is intelHAXM.sys causing BSODs. I ran driver verifier multiple times already and probably eliminated drivers as a likely cause. I ran Windows memory diagnosis and did not get any errors. The BSODs come even when BlueStacks isn't open, so I'm stumped on the real culprit.

Comment: if you think it is intelHAXM check this forum topic: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475129?page=1

Comment: That would be the topic that made me assume it is intelHAXM. It said it was for Windows 8.1 and Mac OSX so I did not know if it would also apply to Windows 7. I did update intelHAXM and currently am waiting for any new BSODs. I will update if there is one.